# Prove $9 \mathrel| (4^n+6n-1)$ by induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction, divisibility

I know that this question was already answered, but I would like to know if the second step of induction its okay the way I did it.

This question is different from [Induction proof for $n\in\mathbb N$, $9 \mathrel| (4^n+6n-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614219/induction-proof-for-n-in-mathbb-n-9-mathrel-4n6n-1) and [Let $n ∈ N, n ≥ 1$. Prove that $4^n + 6n - 1$ is divisible by $9$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589471/let-n-%e2%88%88-n-n-%e2%89%a5-1-prove-that-4n-6n-1-is-divisible-by-9) since it is just about to check a part from a proof that I did (if the way I thought is correct or not).

**Suppose that   $9 \mathrel| (4^k+6k-1)$ is true for $k\in \mathbb{N},  k\geq1$**. I want to prove $P(k+1)$: $ 9 \mathrel| 4^{(k+1)} +6(k+1) - 1$

Since $9 \mathrel| (4^k+6k-1)$, I can rewrite as:

$4^k+6k-1 = 9q$,  where $q \in \mathbb{Z} $. By the definion of Divisibility.

- *Multiplying the equation on both sides by 4, I'll get:*

$4^{(k+1)} +24k-4 = 36q$

- *Adding 3 on both sides*

$4^{(k+1)} +24k - 1 = 36q + 3$

- *Subtracting $18k$ on both sides*

$4^{(k+1)} +6k - 1 = 36q + 3 -18k$

- *Adding 6 in order to have $6(k+1)$ as a factor*

$4^{(k+1)} +6k + 6 - 1 = 36q + 3 -18k + 6$

$4^{(k+1)} +6(k+1) - 1 = 36q + 9 -18k $

Note that $36q + 9 -18k$ can be written like this: $9(4q + 1 - 2k)$. Thus $9Q$, $Q=(4q + 1 - 2k), Q \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Therefore:

- $4^{(k+1)} +6(k+1) - 1 = 9Q$. Which means that $4^{(k+1)} +6(k+1) - 1$ is also divided by 9.

Does my proof look fine? If there is a problem, please tell me. All help is appreciated.

Comment: you haven't started the induction step with $P(k+1)$, so no prize for you

Comment: It's much quicker with congruences.

Comment: I missed it @ganeshie8. Thanks.

Comment: It works.  You got were you were driving through.  Adding $3$ to both sides set my panic button off because we could not longer claim both sides were divisible by $9$ but that wasn't where you aiming the steering wheel after all so it was all good in the end... people point out you can make it shorter and neater but I like that I can see you worked this through on your own.

Comment: Yeah @fleablood. Thanks. I made a lot of comments during the proof even though some were unnecessary, but I did just in order to make it clearly and understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good.  I like it a lot.

But in induction proofs it's often easier to start at the destination and drive backwards through one way streets to the start, rather than starting from the start and driving through a bunch of intersections without a map in order to reach your destination.

$4^{k+1} + 6(k+1) - 1=$

$4*4^{k} + 6k + 5 = $

$4(4^k + 6k -1) - 24k +4 +6k + 5=$

$4(4^k + 6k -1) - 18k +9 = 4(4^k+6k-1) -9(2k-1)$.

And $9|4^k + 6k -1\implies 9|4(4^k+ 6-1) - 9(2k-1)$$

Comment: Yes, I see your point. Both ways are correct. But I wasn't sure enough if I  manipulated correctly.

Comment: You did.  I like what you did.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way: $4^n+6n-1\iff (3+1)^n+6n-1=(9M+3n+1)+6n-1=9(M+n)$

Answer (score 0):

It's fine. Cut to the essentials: just say if $P(k)=9q$ for some $q$ then $P(k+1)=9(4q-2k+1)$, with some minimal computations to justify it:

$$P(k+1)=4^{k+1} + 6(k+1)-1 = 4(4^k) + 6k +5 =\\ 4(9q-6k+1)+ 6k+5 = 
36q - 18k + 9 = 9(4q-2k+1)$$

No "cleverness" needed, it just falls out automatically.

Comment: Or, that the difference $3\cdot 4^k+6$ must divide by 9 leading to $4^k$ always having remainder 1 on division by 3. which is true, proving that the differences are, and so if one element of the original divides by 9, they all do.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I think the OP wants a simple computation style answer as I gave it, no congruences etc.

Comment: you can turn mod into linear polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

If $n \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, then for an integer $k$:

$$4^n + 6n-1 \equiv 4^{3k} + 18k - 1 \equiv 1^k + 0 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 9.$$

If $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, then:

$$4^n + 6n-1 \equiv 4 \cdot4^{3k} + 18k + 6- 1 \equiv 4+0+6-1 \equiv 0 \pmod 9.$$

Finally, if $n \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, we have:

$$4^n + 6n-1 \equiv 16 \cdot4^{3k} + 18k + 12- 1 \equiv 16+0+12-1 \equiv 0 \pmod 9.$$

Since an integer can only congruent to either $0 \pmod 3, 1 \pmod 3$ or $2 \pmod 3$, this completes the proof for all integer $n$.

Comment: You could also derive the answer from $4^n=(1+3)^n\equiv1+3n\pmod9$ for all $n$, but the title of the question asks for a proof by induction

Comment: Alright then, but this was intended as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine. The same work with congruence:
$$4^k+6k-1\equiv 0 \pmod{9}$$
Since $gcd(4,9)=1$, multiply it by $4$:
$$4^{k+1}+24k-4\equiv 4^{k+1}+\require{cancel}\cancel{18k}+6k-4+\color{red}9\equiv 4^{k+1}+6(k+1)-1\equiv 0\pmod{9}.$$

Comment: I appreciate your method! Quicker than mine.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.